# C++ Program Returning Differing Results in IDEs and differing results when running the same data

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Farmer John has acquired a set of N (2 <= N <= 2,000) touchy cows
who are conveniently numbered 1..N. They really hate being too close
to other cows. A lot.

FJ has recorded the integer X_i,Y_i coordinates of every cow i (1
<= X_i <= 100,000; 1 <= Y_i <= 100,000).

Among all those cows, exactly two of them are closest together. FJ
would like to spread them out a bit. Determine which two are closest
together and print their cow id numbers (i) in numerical order.

```
                10 | . . . . . . . 3 . . . . .
                 9 | . 1 . . 2 . . . . . . . .
                 8 | . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                 7 | . . . . . . . . . . 4 . .
                 6 | . . . . . . 9 . . . . . .
                 5 | . 8 . . . . . . . . . . .
                 4 | . . . . . 7 . . . . . . .
                 3 | . . . . . . . . . 5 . . .
                 2 | . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                 1 | . . . . 6 . . . . . . . .
                 0 ---------------------------
                                       1 1 1 1
                   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
```

Quick visual inspection shows that cows 7 and 9 are closest together
(the distance separating them is sqrt(1*1+2*2) = sqrt(5), so the
output would be '7 9' on a single line (without quotes, of course).

Below is my coded attempt to solve the problem:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int n; cin >> n;
   long long xcord[n],ycord[n];

   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       cin >> xcord[i];
       cin >> ycord[i];
   }

   long long shortest = 9999999999999;
   int a=-1, b=-1;
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       for (int j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
           long long curDist = (xcord[i]-xcord[j])*(xcord[i]-xcord[j]) + (ycord[i]-ycord[j])*(ycord[i]-ycord[j]);
           // cout << curDist << " ";
           if (curDist < shortest) {
               shortest = curDist;
               a=i+1, b=j+1;
           }
       }
   }
   cout << a << " " << b << endl;

}
```

Here is the test case I am running:
25
24804 7918
98983 95075
10819 48641
84481 33476
56724 20854
83193 17014
72997 5394
69263 33045
26810 75288
85442 47243
81678 82129
84199 35206
68212 77035
62113 87896
49538 1375
145 90953
58175 62546
73175 5853
7789 37961
18883 49418
78257 90342
2048 64282
49057 95081
89406 47329
9778 68104

When I run the test case using my code, I get the correct answer, 7 18. I am running the code using VSCode. When I try running the code using replit, I get a completely different answer despite the test case being the same and when I try running the same test case over and over in replit, the program returns differing answers. Do you know why I am getting this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ever tried a debugger yourself to find the problem in your code

Comment: Differing behavior usually means there is some undefined behavior in your code. `for (int j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {` looks like it could cause UB  as it appears to be an off by 1 error. `j<=n` is often wrong and is definitely wrong here. Your arrays have valid range of 0 .. n-1 but you access `xcord[j]` which is `xcord[n]` on the last iteration or one element past the end of the xcord array.

Comment: Standard C++ [does not have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) (VLAs). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the error by changing the j<=n to j<n. I'll try an implementation with a vector next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right here you go out of bounds on your array

```
 for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) 
 -----------------------^
```

that should be

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
```

now gives 7 18